# Accordion menu making other div contents to move

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is fiddle ,please check it once
http://jsfiddle.net/Raghava0330/o44ez0qL/

Here is My HTML Code

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href="#"><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Company</span></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer. It's like expressing gratitude or simply giving a vote of thanks to the person who resolved your query. Welcome to SO. @raghava goud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the positioning of the content is related to the menu.

What you should do is give the menu a position, add the following for example.

**CSS:**

```
#cssmenu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o44ez0qL/2/), updated.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: if i want animation for that menu (means it should come from right to left) what i have to do? @Bokdem

Comment: When do you want it to slide in, from right to left?

Comment: Can you create a new question for this?

Comment: I have got the answer for you :)

Comment: No problem, if any other questions please ask! :)